# CiviMail cannot create ACL recipient table after upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.31

Tags: drupal, civimail, database, acl

After upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.31 I began to get several errors while initially trying to send a test e-mail using an ACL-based user.  I noticed that these errors were not happening with the Administrator account.  Upon trying to reuse a previous e-mail I got the following error:

```
> CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such table"
> 
> #0 /public_html/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Controller/Send.php(67):
> civicrm_api3("Mailing", "clone", (Array:1))
> #1 /public_html/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(304):
> CRM_Mailing_Controller_Send->__construct("New Mailing", TRUE, "null",
> NULL, "false")
> #2 /public_html/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
> #3 /public_html/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
> #4 /public_html/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
> #5 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("mailing", "send")
> #6 /public_html/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
> #7 /public_html/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
> #8 {main}
```

I believe that Civi builds a temporary table based on the active user's ACL settings.  This is why this behavior doesn't trigger when using the Administrator account.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you upgrade from (what version were you on prior to this)?

Comment: Upgraded from 4.7.30.  Originally started to have problems such as Mail stuck on Saving and other nuances prior to upgrading.  Problems began after upgrading from 4.7.29 to 4.7.30.